# Extending a class vs code duplication in typescript

Tags: typescript

Can somebody please explain why I would extend a class instead of just make the parameters optional? If I would to extend my class I would just have to duplicate most of the code. How does the DRY principle apply to this?

Example:

```
class Example {
constructor(
public id: number,
public name:string,
public type: string,
public extra?: string // this one is not there when you would extend
) {}
}
```

vs:

```
class ExampleExtended extends Example {
constructor(
public id: number,
public name: string,
public type: string,
public extra: string
)
super(id, name, type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to repeat the properties in your child class?

Extending (Inheriting) gives access to your base class properties in your derived class.

Comment: How would you create an instance of the child class without it? -> new ExampleExtended(etc, etc)

Comment: As soon as you inherit from a class it automatically has the base classes properties. Just use the properties from the derived class instance

Comment: Yeah as when you are using any instance of any class, it saves you recreating properties on your derived class when you are coding them, using an instance is the same as if you had duplicated the properties in two classes and not inherited. At these points I usually stop and ask myself if I'm seriously say that x or y can't be right. You're essentially saying that the OO world has got it all wrong with inheritance and it's not a good idea. Of course looking at some object graphs I might agree with that thought but that's different :)